# Oracle password contains slashes

Tags: oracle, zend-framework

I am using the zend:auth adapters with an oracle connection.
I am trying to authenticate a user at login.  The authentication goes off without a hitch if the user
enters regular alphanum but when a password is like this (for example) `IUCJAC\_` the validation for authentication returns false.

I have tried:

- Zend_View::escape();
- Zend_DB_Adapter::quote();
- php's addslashed();

to no avail.

Any ideas?

```
public function authAction()
{
    //Returns encrypted password
    $newpass = new Application_Model_Discoverpw();
    $this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender();
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $password =$newpass->encode_password(trim($_POST['password']));
        $slashedPW =  $db->quote($password);
        $formValues = array(
        'email' => $_POST['email'], 'password' => $slashedPW);

        if ($this->_process($formValues)) {

            // We're authenticated! Redirect to the home page
            //echo '{"success":true}';
            $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'sam');

            //$this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');

        } else {
           throw new Zend_Auth_Exception('Login failed! '. $sql);
            //echo 'oh no!';
        }
    } else {
        //Redirect to login page if no $_POST values found
        $this->_helper->redirector('login', 'userauth');
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `_process` method do? It seems like this is where the quoting should happen, if anywhere

Comment: What version of Oracle are you on? There were more restrictions in 10g and earlier than there are in 11.

Comment: Why would the the password that is entered on the page interact in anyway with the password hash (it is a hash isn't it?) in the database. Is it possible that the password is failing your input validation or being filtered in such a way the the hashes no longer match?